# Debian: How to access GPIO without root permissions

Tags: c++, c, debian, gpio

I’m using a C program to read/write GPIO pins, but there is the problem: I’m using ioperm to give permissions to do write / read operations on ports, but I really need to run this program without root privileges (the error is “Segmentation fault” …)
Is there any way to do this? (not doing setuid…)
//something like that to test

```
void setIo(unsigned char value)
{
    iopl(3);
    ioperm(PORT_IO,1,1); 
    outb(value,PORT_IO); 
    ioperm(PORT_IO,1,0);
}
```

Thank you.
Monique

Comment: Had similar problem, try this... http://robosavvy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6076 alternatively you could write a character device driver for the pins and use that (map it to /dev/)

Comment: thanks! but then my question is... How can i let all GPIO with write permission? it's not mapped, only addresses...

Comment: Run the code automaticaly after boot strapping

Comment: I have tried to run ioperm(PORT_IO,1,1) automatically as root but when I try to do outb(value, PORT_IO) as user without root privileges I get "Segmentation fault" again...

Comment: Try `sudo` it for your user... I think that does the trick, I can't remember many details though... I had a little bit different problem

Comment: thanks! it was my second choice.. I can see it's the only way...